# Google Drive Web API save and download pdf

Tags: javascript, typescript, pdf, google-drive-api

I am trying to get a pdf from google drive and download it in the browser (I actually need it as an array buffer or blob to use it with pspdfkit, but this dose the same thing and it's simpler to describe). I tried it in many ways so far and couldn't get a pdf from the response I got from the api.

I want to specify that this is part of an angular 10 app, but I don't think it's to relevant. Also I need to specify that I am using typescript, but I also did a js version to test, same seem to produce the same result.

The `doc` object comes from the google drive picker `google.picker.PickerBuilder`

This is the code I use to get the file contents

```
gapi.client.drive.files
 .get({
  fileId: doc.id,
  alt: 'media',
  // mimeType: 'application/pdf', // <- with or without
  // responseType: 'arraybuffer', // <- with or without
 })
 .then((res) => {
  // manipulate res.body
  window.resb=res.body;
  // HERE <- I continue to call saveFile and debug the response
 });
```

This is the function I use to test if I can use the response as a pdf file:

```
function saveFile(blob, filename) {
  if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
    window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, filename);
  } else {
    const a = document.createElement('a');
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    a.href = url;
    a.download = filename;
    a.click();
    setTimeout(() => {
      window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
      document.body.removeChild(a);
    }, 0)
  }
}
```

This is another function that I try and parse the string to an arraybuffer

```
function str2ab(str) {
  var buf = new ArrayBuffer(str.length*2); // 2 bytes for each char
  var bufView = new Uint16Array(buf);
  for (var i=0, strLen=str.length; i < strLen; i++) {
    bufView[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return buf;
}
```

This is how I actually call the `download` function

```
saveFile(new Blob([resb],{type: 'application/pdf',}),'a.pdf'); // <- only one that actually produces an openable pdf file, but empty
```

or

```
saveFile(new Blob([str2ab(resb)],{type: 'application/pdf',}),'a.pdf');
```

or

```
saveFile(new Blob(str2ab(resb),{type: 'application/pdf',}),'a.pdf');
```

... and a few other methods.

I am fresh out of ideas and I am at `a (618).pdf`. Please help :)

EDIT: attaching partial `console.log(resb);` [image: resb]

Comment: Where/when exactly are you calling `saveFile`? Because you need to call it inside the final `.then` callback in your drive api code, or `resb` will be empty.

Comment: I call it after the resb is populated with data. I will add an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to download a PDF file from Google Drive using Javascript.
- Your `gapi.client` can be used for downloading the file.

In this case, I would like to propose to modify the script for converting from the binary data to blob.

#### Modified script:

A simple modified script is as follows. When you run this script, a PDF file is downloaded and save it to the local PC as a file.

```
gapi.client.drive.files
 .get({
  fileId: doc.id,
  alt: 'media',
 })
 .then((res) => {
   const filename = "sample.pdf";
   
   // Convert binary data to blob.
   const data = res.body;
   const len = data.length;
   const ar = new Uint8Array(len);
   for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
     ar[i] = data.charCodeAt(i);
   }
   const blob = new Blob([ar], {type: 'application/pdf'});
   
   // Save the file.
   const a = document.createElement('a');
   document.body.appendChild(a);
   const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
   a.href = url;
   a.download = filename;
   a.click();
 });
```

#### Reference:

- [Download files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads)

Comment: It seems that my only issues was concerting it to an Uint8Array before transforming it to a blob. Thanks.

Comment: @cuzzea Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you.