# How can I fetch an audio file from Google Drive using v3 of the JavaScript API?

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I am trying to write some code to parse the ID3 tags from a given Google Drive file.  The [API docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get) suggest I should call `gapi.client.drive.files.get` with the file ID and `alt: 'media'` parameter, and then make a `new File([response.body], fileName, { type: mimeType })` that I can then pass to the tag parsing library.  While that seems to work fine for text files, the binary data doesn't make it through, and the resulting file doesn't have correctly readable tags (or playable audio data, for that matter).  My best guess is some issue with character encoding is messing up the binary string (similar to why `FileReader` `readAsBinaryString` was deprecated), but I haven't found a way in the Drive API to avoid this or a workaround to salvage the data from the string the Drive API returns.

(Edit) The initial approach that failed was:

```js
let fileRes = await gapi.client.drive.files.get({
    fileId: fileData.id,
    alt: 'media'
}),
    file = new File([fileRes.body], fileData.name, { type: fileData.mimeType }),
    audio = new Audio();
audio.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
audio.controls = true;
document.body.appendChild(audio);
```

Comment: In your situation, for example, is this thread useful? https://stackoverflow.com/q/64739841 If this was not useful, in order to correctly understand your current issue, can you provide your current script?

Comment: @Tanaike I could have sworn I tried something like that, but evidently not because that approach worked!  Thank you so much!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. From your reply, I flagged it as the duplicated question of https://stackoverflow.com/q/64739841

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What seems to work (thank you to @Tanaike for pointing me in the right direction!) is:

```js
let fileRes = await gapi.client.drive.files.get({
        fileId: fileData.id,
        alt: 'media'
    }),
    dataArr = Uint8Array.from(fileRes.body.split('').map((chr) => chr.charCodeAt(0))),
    file = new File([dataArr], fileData.name, { type: fileData.mimeType }),
    audio = new Audio();
audio.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
audio.controls = true;
document.body.appendChild(audio);
```